# Prevent click after focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When user clicks on input field, two consecutive events are being executed: `focus` and `click`.

`focus` always gets executed first and shows the notice. But `click` which runs immediately after `focus` hides the notice. I only have this problem when input field is not focused and both events get executed consecutively.

I'm looking for the clean solution which can help me to implement such functionality (without any timeouts or weird hacks).

**HTML**:

```
<label for="example">Example input: </label>
<input type="text" id="example" name="example" />
<p id="notice" class="hide">This text could show when focus, hide when blur and toggle show/hide when click.</p>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#example').on('focus', _onFocus)
             .on('blur', _onBlur)
             .on('click', _onClick);

function _onFocus(e) {  
    console.log('focus');

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $('#notice').removeClass('hide');
}

function _onClick(e) {
   console.log('click');
   $('#notice').toggleClass('hide');
}

function _onBlur(e) {
    console.log('blur');
    $('#notice').addClass('hide');
}
```

**UPDATED Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtemFitiskin/3Bev4/12/):**

Comment: Is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/3Bev4/11/

Comment: Why are you not using addClass() and removeClass() combination on _onFocus and _onBlur. Is toggle-ing a class on click event really necessary?

Comment: @abhitalks No. Click should toggle show/hide by itself

Comment: @SurajKumar Yes, it's necessary. It's simple example, in real code another reason to use it.

Comment: @ArtemFitiskin: updated the fiddle and added as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you jumbled up the toggles. No need to prevent propagation and all that. Just check if the notice is already visible when `click` fires.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bev4/13/**

*Code*:

```
var $notice = $('#notice'); // cache the notice

function _onFocus(e) {  
    console.log('focus');
    $notice.removeClass('hide'); // on focus show it
}

function _onClick(e) {
   console.log('click');
    if ($notice.is('hidden')) { // on click check if already visible
       $notice.removeClass('hide'); // if not then show it
    }
}

function _onBlur(e) {
    console.log('blur');
    $notice.addClass('hide'); // on blur hide it
}
```

Hope that helps.

***Update***: *based on OP's clarification on click toggling*:

Just cache the focus event in a state variable and then based on the state either show the notice or toggle the class.

**Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bev4/19/**

*Updated code*:

```
var $notice = $('#notice'), isfocus = false; 

function _onFocus(e) {  
    isFocus = true; // cache the state of focus
    $notice.removeClass('hide');
}

function _onClick(e) {
    if (isFocus) { // if focus was fired, show/hide based on visibility
        if ($notice.is('hidden')) { $notice.removeClass('hide'); }
        isFocus = false; // reset the cached state for future
    } else {
        $notice.toggleClass('hide'); // toggle if there is only click while focussed
    }
}
```

***Update 2***: based on OP's observation on first click after tab focus:

On second thought, can you just bind the `mousedown` or `mouseup` instead of `click`? That will not fire the focus.

**Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bev4/24/**

*Updated code*:

```
$('#example').on('focus', _onFocus)
             .on('blur', _onBlur)
             .on('mousedown', _onClick);

var $notice = $('#notice');
function _onFocus(e) { $notice.removeClass('hide'); }
function _onClick(e) { $notice.toggleClass('hide'); }
function _onBlur(e) { $notice.addClass('hide'); }
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but in your solution click not working as toggler. Look at my fiddle and try clicking on a field several times

Comment: @ArtemFitiskin: Ok now I got what you are trying to convey. There, updated the answer.

Comment: you have similar problem with Rob Schmuecker answer. First click on focused field will not anything (expected hide the notice)

Comment: Also, i have idea with setTimeout, but it is not clear solution. _onFocus -->  isFocus = true; setTimeout(function () { isFocus = false }, 500);

Comment: @ArtemFitiskin: Updated the answer again. Can you just bind the mousedown or mouseup instead of click? That will not fire the focus. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bev4/21/

Comment: Nice answer @abhitalks - I think you've got the solution ;)

Comment: Thanks to you @abhitalks, I've decided a real problem, but I do not know whether to close issue considering the context of this problem. I knew about this decision: `mousedown` activated before `focus` and you solved the problem. But strictly speaking, my question was how to prevent `click` event after `focus`.

Comment: @ArtemFitiskin: *..how to prevent click event after focus* - You can't, unless you hack your way around. One hack could be to unbind `click` just after the `focus` and rebind on `blur`. But, I am not sure how that will actually help you. **See this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4YNQ5/1/**

Comment: @abhitalks I know these decisions. I just put that to lose sight of something more obvious, but nobody know it and your answer best :)

Comment: Thanks @Abhitalks, this helped me a ton. Did not know that mousedown did not fire focus!

Answer (score 2):

Setting a variable for "focus" seems to do the trick : http://jsfiddle.net/3Bev4/9/

Javascript:

```
$('#example').on('focus', _onFocus)
    .on('click', _onClick)
    .on('blur', _onBlur);
focus = false;

function _onFocus(e) {
    console.log('focus');
    $('#notice').removeClass('hide');

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    focus = true;
}

function _onClick(e) {
    console.log('click');
    if (!focus) {
        $('#notice').toggleClass('hide');
    } else {
        focus = false;
    }
}

function _onBlur(e) {
    console.log('blur');
    $('#notice').addClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: I fully understand this method, but if you use the Tab button to select the field (notice show corrently) and click it you reach else statement of your _onClick (nothing happens, must be hide).

Comment: +1 @Rob. Am sorry I didn't notice your answer earlier until the OP asked me to. Otherwise I wouldn't have attempted in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the notice onBlur, surely it needs to be:

```
function _onBlur(e) {
    console.log('blur');
    $('#notice').addClass('hide'); // Add the hidden class, not remove it
}
```

When doing this in the fiddle, it seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use many jQuery methods rather than add or move class:

**Update: add a params to deal with the click function**
http://jsfiddle.net/3Bev4/23/

```
var showNotice = false;
$('#example').focus(function(){
     $('#notice').show();
     showNotice = true;
}).click(function(){
    if(showNotice){                
         $('#notice').show();
        showNotice = false;
    }else{
         showNotice = true;
        $('#notice').hide();
    }


}).blur(function(){
     $('#notice').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Your solution will not work if you use the Tab button to select the field (focus without click does not show the notice).

Comment: add a params so that we can deal with the click function

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written is correct, except that you have to replae `$('#notice').removeClass('hide');` with `$('#notice').addClass('hide');`

Because **onBlur** you want to hide so add hide class, instead you are removing the "hide" calss.

I hope this is what the mistake you have done.
Correct if I am wrong, Because I don't know JQuery much, I just know JavaScript.